# WEHRE IN array values using stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, memsql, singlestore

I have a select query that uses a `WHERE IN` clause in a MemSQL database. The list of values searched in are a result of another select query.

Before, I inserted the values for that clause as a string through a web service like so: `(1,2,3..)`.

Now I want to move the second query into a stored procedure, and have the values mentioned above be a part of the parameters for that procedure.

Say I have a table:

```
create table t (num int);
```

Then when I try to create the sp:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test (nums ARRAY(INT)) AS 
BEGIN
ECHO SELECT * FROM t WHERE num IN nums;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): Compilation error in function `test` near line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nums'
```

So apparently it doesn't work that way. Is there way I can get this to recognize the data type I'm inserting?
I want to avoid manipulating strings, but if there is no choice, would it require running the query as a string in the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding nums in brackets so it can complete the required syntax.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test (nums ARRAY(INT)) 
AS 
BEGIN
ECHO SELECT * FROM t WHERE num 
IN(nums);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```